# Filter specific line in a file in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I've got this txt file

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

Version : 2.3
Date    : 2019-06-21

New Features:
-------------
ID        : 1P
des       : toto

ID        : 2P
des       : tata

Fixed Bugs:

-----------
ID        : 2D
des       : lala

-------------------------------------------------------------------------

Version : 2.2
Date    : 2019-06-21

New Features:
-------------
ID        : 1O
des       : toto

ID        : 2o
des       : tata

Fixed Bugs:

-----------
ID        : 2O
des       : lala

-------------------------------------------------------------------------

Version : 2.1
Date    : 2019-06-21

New Features:
-------------
ID        : 1E
des       : toto

ID        : 2E
des       : tata

Fixed Bugs:

-----------
ID        : 2D
des       : lala

-------------------------------------------------------------------------


Version : 2.0
Date    : 2019-06-21

New Features:
-------------
ID        : 1P
des       : toto

ID        : 2P
des       : tata

Fixed Bugs:

-----------
ID        : 2D
des       : lala
```

I have a test.js file :

```
// Some script 
diffList.push({
                components: element,
                newVersion: listComponentsFromHead[key],    //2.3
                oldVersion: listComponentsFromLastTag[key], // 2.1
            });

diffList.forEach((element) => {
try {
    const data = fs.readFileSync('file.txt', 'UTF-8');
    const lines = data.split('\n');
    lines.forEach((line) => {
        if(line.startsWith("Version : " + element.newVersion)){
                console.log(line);
        }
    });
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
}
})
```

For now, I'm parsing and get only all line who starts with Version

How can I do the next what I need to do it's to retrieve all ID inside a array between newVersion and OldVersion.

For example in my case, between 2.3 and 2.1, I want something like this :

- [1P, 2P, 2D, 1O, 2O, 2O, 1E, 2E, 2D]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Once you find new version line, get ready to read the id lines (say parseMode)

2) During the parse mode, extract the `id` values using the regex and push to array

3) When you find old version line, means you can stop parsing id values.

This sample code should work, Try replace the your `try` block. Hope this helps.

```
const data = fs.readFileSync("file.txt", "UTF-8");
const lines = data.split("\n");
let parseMode = false;
const results = []; // array of arrays.
const arr = []; // array for one diff
lines.forEach(line => {
  if (line.startsWith("Version : " + element.newVersion)) {
    parseMode = true;
    arr.length = 0; // initialize arr to be empty
  } else if (line.startsWith("Version : " + element.oldVersion) && parseMode) {
    parseMode = false;
    results.push(arr);
  } else if (parseMode) {
    // extract the id using the regex.
    const id = line.match(/^ID\s+:\s(.+)/)[1];
    arr.push[id];
  }
});

console.log(results);
```

Comment: Got a error: "Cannot read property '1' of null"
What do you mean by [1] in regex @Siva Kondapi Venkata

Comment: oh got it, missed to check that. Glad to hear @fzefzefzefzef. :)